# how can I put my textfield input stay center vertically?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to put a `textFiled` in a `Container`. But I found the input content couldn't stay vertically certer(a bit higher) in the `Container` but the two `icons` displayed well. Is there a solution to my situation?
[image]

```
Container(
                      width: ScreenAdapt.widthToDp(330),
                      height: ScreenAdapt.heightToDp(40),
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: inputController,
                        focusNode: focusNode,
                        style: MyTextStyle.level4,
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          prefixIcon: MyIcon.SearchGreyIcon,
                          hintText: 'hint text here',
                          hintStyle: MyTextStyle.grey,
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                          suffixIcon: focusNode.hasFocus ? IconButton(
                            icon: MyIcon.CloseIcon,
                            onPressed: () => inputController.clear(),
                          ) : Container(),
                        ),
                      ),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: MyColor.MidGray,
                        borderRadius: MyStyle.CIRCULAR_BORDER_RADIUS,
                      ),
                    ),
```

Comment: can you try `filled: true,contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(15)` in `decoration: InputDecoration()`@byhuang1998

Comment: @Assassin yes, it works, thanks for your help. Can I bother you to explain its principle to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this as  @Assassin Suggested

```
InputDecoration(
        prefixIcon: MyIcon.SearchGreyIcon,
        hintText: 'hint text here',
        hintStyle: MyTextStyle.grey,
        border: InputBorder.none,
        filled: true,
        suffixIcon: focusNode.hasFocus
            ? IconButton(
                icon: MyIcon.CloseIcon,
                onPressed: () => inputController.clear(),
              )
            : Container(),
      )
```

Comment: Oh, thanks for your advice it works. Can you explain its principle to me?

Comment: please visit here for more info https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/filled.html